# opentbs deleting spaces

Tags: php, docx, xlsx, opentbs

I'm using openTBS to convert data from a mysql db (via PHP) to some word and excel docs.

One of my problems is, openTBS is deleting lots of spaces near the tags..

```
blablabla [base_sub1.value] blablabla
```

and the output is

```
blablablavalue blablabla
```

or

```
blablablavalueblablabla
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ms Word often cut the inner XML content because of formating, spelling and version history.
This may cause OpenTBS to loose some space at those place because dealing with attribute  `xml:space="preserve"` becomes too complicated.

Since OpenTBS version 1.7.6, such space problem are fixed in the main body. There may still have problems in other special parts such as headers and footers.

Otherwise, most of the time if you cut the TBS tag and paste it on the same place that fixes the problem. Or cut and do a special paste as "Unformatted text".

Otherwise, in order to avoid the space errors, you must do as following during the template edition:

1. Avoid internal Review markers:

   - If you have Word 2003, go to the menu Tools, choose Options, then tab Security and uncheck the box “Store random number to improve
     merge accuracy”.
   - If you have Word 2007 or higher, go to the Trust Center in the Word options, and turn off the setting: "Store random number to
     improve combine accuracy".
   - If you have Office for Mac 2011, then unfortunately this option does not exist yet. Try to copy all the document and past in a new document.
2. Avoid Spelling markers: Each time you enter a new TBS tag or each
   time you apply a format over a TBS tag, select it and click on the
   Review ribbon, in the Proofing group, click the Set Language button.
   In the dialog, make sure the "Do not check spelling or grammar" box
   is checked.

Comment: i did that, and didnt work... sometimes it delete spaces sometimes dont.. :S but thks for ur answer... well, im using version 1.7.4, maybe its because of that, ill try the new one, and post ;)

Comment: So we need the template for a deeper understanding of the problem.

Comment: YAHHHH DUDE!!! was my bad!!! :( sorry, with 1.7.6 version im having all my spaces xD ty a lot